# Dell Inspiron 570 + Sapphire R9 280X

Tags: graphics-card, motherboard, amd-radeon, dell-inspiron

I bought a Sapphire Tri-X R9 280X to replace my old HD 3450, and moved my PC's components to a much larger case with a new 850W PSU. The card fit, but when I powered the PC on, I hear 9 beeps, and nothing is displayed. I know nothing is wrong with the mobo or anything else because the PC boots fine when I remove the new GPU and put the old one back (still inside the new case with the new PSU). Is this a known problem with the Inspiron 570 mobo, or should I RMA my card?

Comment: Are you certain it is 9 beeps? If you have your manual, I believe there should be a table of bios beep codes. If you don't but you remember what BIOS brand your pc has you can look up the codes that way. There is also a table [http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/desktop/w/desktop/3624.beep-codes-and-psa-diagnostic-chart](Dell Beep Codes)

Comment: I usually only hear 1 beep when booting my computer (this seems normal to me). With the new GPU I hear that 1 beep, then a short break, then 8 more beeps.

Comment: In fact, now that I think about it, the first time I powered it on, I heard that one beep followed by 5 more. According to the beep code table, that is a GPU failure. I'll go ahead and RMA my card, and I'll see if the replacement has this problem too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I should have come back here last month! Anyways, it was because I was trying to run the 300W card off a single rail on my quad-rail PSU, which could only give 240W. Once I figured that out and split the card between 2 rails, it worked perfectly.